# where is all my memory in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, top

When I do top it says `KiB Mem:  15396812 total` and `14917020 used`. Divide those into one another and you get about 96.8% memory usage.

BUT...  in the process list, in the `%MEM` column it shows 40.5% for mysql and then a bunch of 0.2, 0.1 and 0.0 entries. All of these 0.2, 0.1 and 0.0 added together do not add up to even close to 96.8% so where is all the memory going?

Comment: its probably in cache. run `sudo free` and add together all the values in the column "Free".  Does this value more closely match what top is saying?

Comment: also the numbers 0.2, 0.1, 0.0 are system load averages for various durations.